# Django admin Add item button translation

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am struggling with the translation of an add button in django admin site. The one in the image below.

[image: Admin button]

I have a classmethod which gets the right accusative form

```py
@classmethod
def accusative_case(cls):
    return pgettext("accusative", "User")
```

And the translation in django.po file

```
#: .\accounts\models.py:82
msgctxt "accusative"
msgid "User"
msgstr "Użytkownika"
```

How can i change its text so it takes the right form?

Comment: This is dynamic: In English it's "Add" + <verbose name of model>. Do you need to change the "Add" translation or the name of your model? In the latter case, this is the `verbose_name` variable you set in the `Meta` of your model.

Comment: The problem is that in polish language "User" is "Użytkownik, but "Add User" is "Dodaj Użytkownika". I have a classmethod which takes the right form, but have no idea where to put it to make it work.